# Function looks like a distribution curve

Tags: graphing-functions

I was playing around with Desmos and noticed that the graph of $y=(x^2+1)^{-1}$ looks like a distribution. I know that distributions like the normal distribution follow the form of $a^{-x^2}$. Are these functions related at all? Does the function I've mentioned have any use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density function
$$f(x)=\frac1{\pi(1+x^2)}$$
defines the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). It's a great example
in probability theory. It has no mean, no variance, and does not
satisfy the central limit theorem!